# Includepdf as a figure

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I want to include some pages of a `pdf` file into my document and wrap them into a figure with a caption for example (with `pdfpages`)

```
\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering      
   \includepdf[pages={1,3,2},nup=2x2]{test.pdf}      
 \caption{Test}
 \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
```

However this doesn't work. So is there another way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you need to include these the "traditional" way, via `\includegraphics` on an image-by-image (or page-by-page) way. Also, `\label` should be *after* `\caption` *always*.

Comment: @Werner Can `\includegraphics` select a particular page from a `pdf`-file? I also tried to to something like `\includgraphics{\includepdf{...}}`.

Comment: Yes, `\includegraphics[page=1]{file}`, for example.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As already said by others in the comments you need to use `\includegraphics` directly because `\includepdf` uses a page of its own. You can use a `tabular` to get the 2x2 layout and use the `page=<number>` key to select the page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hspace{.5cm}}c@{}}
       \includegraphics[page=1,width=.45\textwidth]{somemultipagepdf} & 
       \includegraphics[page=2,width=.45\textwidth]{somemultipagepdf} \\[.5cm]
       \includegraphics[page=3,width=.45\textwidth]{somemultipagepdf} \\
   \end{tabular}
 \caption{Test}
 \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

[`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) typically inserts page breaks before inserting content, causing problems if you want to have an arrangement if pages inside a `figure` environment. Instead, use the `page` key-value of `\includegraphics` itself to insert the contents on a page-by-page basis. Something like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[page=1,width=.3\textwidth]{test}\hspace*{.25\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[page=3,width=.3\textwidth]{test}

  \includegraphics[page=2,width=.3\textwidth]{test}
  \caption{Test}
  \label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
```

If you want the last "image" (`page=2`) to be shown in a `nup=2x2` fashion, you could add `\hspace*{.55\textwidth}` after it, otherwise it will be horizontally centred below the two "images" (`page=1` and `page=3`) above it.

Of course, you can play with the `width` adjustment to suit your liking.

Answer (score 1):

It works if the figure environment is not used.

Simply put

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{test.pdf}
```

The only problem is that the captions need to be provided with \captionof but then may not appear on the last page of the pdf included.

Comment: The only reason to use figure environment in this case was to use captions and labels correctly. If there is a way to get the captions correctly on the last page or each of the pages, please add that solution. \captionof works but is not on same page as the table.

Comment: Can we change its sizing?