# Include PDF on the same page

Tags: graphics, pdf

I would like to append the several-pages .pdf directly after the section-heading.

```
\subsection{Kopie des Projektantrages}
\includepdf[pages=-, fitpaper=true]{\antrag} // my PDF file-command
```

... but it's inserting the pdf on a new page...

Do you know what i try to achive? Hope someone can help me.

Second Try:

```
    \includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\subsection{Kopie des Projektantrages}, fitpaper=true]{\antrag}
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={}, fitpaper=true]{\antrag}
```

Now the Headlines of the latex document and the pdf are colliding...

Comment: Hi. Is this a page or several pages? If it is only a page you can include it with \includegraphics[]{Something.pdf}

Comment: serval pages... tried it with pagecommand to add subsection but then the headline of the latex-document is colliding with the pdfs headline...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This solves the problem :-)

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\subsection{Kopie des Projektantrages} \thispagestyle{empty}}, fitpaper=true]{\antrag}
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}}, fitpaper=true]{\antrag}
```

Answer (score 10):

`\inlcludepdf` always inserts the content on separate pages, because it inserts the pdf-*document* into your document. If you want the pdf to appear *on a page within your document* you have to use `\includegraphics`, which works perfectly fine with pdf files as images in pdflatex.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\subsection{Kopie des Projektantrages}
\includegraphics{antrag.pdf}
```

Edit: In regard to Dolphins comment: Yes, I think that only works when the pdf file has only one page.

Comment: this don't help with several pages.

Comment: @DanielBocksteger I see, but I think what you want to achieve is not so easy then. As I understand it you want to include a pdf of your application in another document. Have you considered not to insert a header in the document but only in your document toc (and maybe pdf-toc) by manually setting an anchor to the first page of the pdf?

Comment: Solved this :-) Look @ my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried various suggestions out there include this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176188/104699. It is either that they do not work as they claim or are too complicated to follow (e.g. the link above). If you are a beginner or use Lyx because you love the GUI, you know how frustrating it is to spend time hacking with tex code. Here is a very simple solution that I found:

1. Include the first page as a graphic using INSERT>GRAPHICS
2. include the rest of the pages as pdf via INSERT>FILE>EXTERNALMATERIAL

   ```
   \section{NAME OF SECTION}
   \includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight]{\string"FILENAME".pdf}
   \includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, pages={2-last},scale=0.8]{LINKTOFILE}
   ```

That simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree, This is a working code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{1\linewidth}}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{1.pdf}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{2.pdf}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable for a fast proof.

Comment: Thanks, The above code is working

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the code idea above as a function that allows for its direct use with `\includepdf`.

```
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}% added for \includepdf

% function for creating a section and attaching a PDF on the same page
\newcommand{\pdfsection}[2]{\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\section{#1} }, width=0.75\textheight]{#2}
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={}, width=0.75\textheight]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\pdfsection{Your section header}{Your file path}

\end{document}
```