# How to include pdf without it always starting on a new page

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

When including a pdf in my document I use:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{myfile.pdf}
```

For some reason every time that I do this it wants to start the pdf on a new page. I would like to start it without going to a new page. Is this possible in LaTeX?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453497/170109

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Suppose that you are at the middle of a page when you entered your command `\includepdf[pages=-]{myfile.pdf}`, would you like LaTeX to put 1.5 pages into 1 page or start the included document at a new page? I see the second option to be logical. If you really need to insert the first page of the document at that very location, use `includegraphics` instead for the first page, then include the rest of pages.